# CollectionView inside Tableview loading incorrect data for reused cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

My purpose is to show the header string in each label of collectionview cell.But when I run the top cells which have already loaded are showing correct values in labels while after scrolling the reused cells are showing incorrect values.
Note : The data is fetched from a local file.

My data is as follows:

- Trending : 20 items
- Mustwatch : 3 items
- Newly Added : 8 Items
- Popular : 2 items

My code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {



var videosList:[VideosJSONElement]?
var videosListInstance:VideosDataAccessModel?

@IBOutlet weak var categoriesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    videosListInstance = VideosDataAccessModel()
    
    videosList = videosListInstance?.videosList
    categoriesTableView.dataSource = self
    categoriesTableView.delegate = self
    
    
    categoriesTableView.reloadData()
    
    
    
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  videosList!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoriesCell") as! CategoriesVideoCell
    cell.videos = videosList![indexPath.row].nodes
    cell.position = indexPath.row
    cell.categoryTitle.text  = videosList![indexPath.row].title
    cell.videosCollectionView.reloadData()
    cell.sceneContext = self

    return cell
}
}
```

CategoriesVideoCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesVideoCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var categoryTitle: UILabel!
    var videos:[Node]?
var position:Int!

var sceneContext:UIViewController?

@IBOutlet weak var videosCollectionView: UICollectionView!


override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    videosCollectionView.dataSource = self
    videosCollectionView.delegate = self
}



override class func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return videos!.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for:indexPath) as! VideoCVCell

    
    cell.node = "\(categoryTitle.text!)"
    return cell
}}
```

[image]

The first two cells have correct label text

[image]

The reused cells have incorrect data in the label

Comment: In your table view cell for row method first set position and after that reload your collection.  
cell.position = indexPath.row             cell.videosCollectionView.reloadData()

Comment: Done , but still no success

Comment: Can you try to set collection view delegate- data sources method inside the awakeFromNib method of table cell class.

Comment: @RajaKishan `Cannot assign value of type 'CategoriesVideoCell.Type' to type 'UICollectionViewDataSource?' `  its showing this error when added in awakeFromNib

Comment: Remove class word from awake from method. Just write override func awakeFromNib()

Comment: Done setting the delegates in awakeFromNib.But still the bottom cells (Newly added & Popular) after scrolling are showing incorrect data.